# In ionic how to read and display the information from firestore

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

In ionic, I want to get and display information from firestore from its specific fields like Name there, but the problem is that it is displaying other documents' field Names too.

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.authService.readc().subscribe(data => {

   this.datas = data.map(e => {
     return {
     Name: e.payload.doc.data()['Name'],
    };
  })
    console.log(this.datas);
  });
}
}

name() {

    var counter = this.firestore.doc(`info/${this.authService.userDetails().uid}`);
    counter.set({
      Name: this.Name
    })
  }
```

**In authService**

```
readc() {
    return this.firestore.collection('info').snapshotChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

**home.page.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  names: any;

  constructor(auth: AuthService) {
    auth.readc().subscribe(data => {
      this.names = data.map(person => ({ name: person.name }));
    });
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  people: any;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.people = db.collection('people').valueChanges();
  }

  readc(){
    return this.people;
  }
}
```

Check out the [angularfire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) for more detailed information on using Collections and Documents in Firebase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thank you for helping me here is question explained please help me -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043952/in-ionic-app-i-want-to-display-the-data-stored-in-firebase-firestore-to-the-app

Comment: registerUser(value){
   
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)

    this.firestore.doc(`users/${value.email}`).set({
      email: value.email,
    })

Comment: this is how i set document