# In ionic app, I want to display the data stored in firebase firestore to the app

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

In ionic, I want to display the user's email and location which are stored in firestore, but the user's firestore document id is their email address. How can i get their data and display to them

**In authentication.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore){}

  registerUser(value){

     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)

     this.firestore.doc(`users/${value.email}`).set({
      Email: value.email
    })
  }


  userDetails(){
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
  }
}
```

**In display.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      User Welcome
    </ion-title>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<div *ngFor="let item of info>
      <h1>{{ item.Email }}</h1> 
    </div>

  <ion-button (click)="logout()">Log Out</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**In display.page.ts**, I have given code to add email and location to firestore now i want to display the data what i am doing is

**display.page.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.authService.read().subscribe(data => {

      this.info = data.map(e => {
        return {
          Email: e.payload.doc.data()['Email'],
          Location: e.payload.doc.data()['Location'],
        };
      })
      console.log(this.info);
    });
}
```

**In authentication.ts**

```
read() {
    return this.firestore.collection('users').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

**The problem is it displaying all the documents data**

Answer (score 0):

In your service you could use something like this to retrieve that user's data:

```
getUser(id: string) {
   return this.firestore.collection('users').doc(id).get();
}
```

Then you call this function within your component like this passing your key (email in your case):

```
this.someService.getUser(email).then((value) => {
    console.log(value.data)
}
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined
FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined this error pops

Comment: You are not passing properly your variable to your function, check that the ID is being properly passed as an argument. Your service function is getting that variable as undefined.

Comment: please tell me how to do that

Comment: In your ngOnInit method you need to call getUser from your service and pass the email as an argument to the function. Are you saving that email somewhere in your service or in localStorage? You need that variable